# MsDeploy is returning 403 forbidden

Tags: .net, iis-7, msdeploy

We had a Web Application working on an intranet and I'm trying to publish it to the internet using Visual Studio 2010. The destination server is running iis7 and the Web Management Service is running.

On Visual Studio 2010 my service URL is:

> https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8172/MsDeploy.axd

And site/application is:

> Default Web Site/WebApp

Marking as IIS App on destination and Allow untrusted certificate is checked and i'm using an administration account.

Visual Studio return the following error:

> Start Web Deploy Publish the Application/package to
>   https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=Default%20Web%20Site ...
>   C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3588,5):
>   Error : Web deployment task failed.(Remote agent (URL
>   https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=Default Web Site) could
>   not be contacted.  Make sure the remote agent service is installed and
>   started on the target computer.)
>
> Remote agent (URL
>   https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=Default Web Site) could
>   not be contacted.  Make sure the remote agent service is installed and
>   started on the target computer. An unsupported response was received.
>   The response header 'MSDeploy.Response' was '' but 'v1' was expected.
>   **The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.**

Any ideas how to publish it without a valid SSL certificate?

Answer (score 266, accepted):

If you go into IIS,
Click on the server node in the "Connections" list,
Double click "Management Service" then you are taken to a screen which has an "Enable remote connections" check box.
This checkbox (and the rest of the sreen) maybe greyed out because the service is running.  Just click the "Stop" link in the Actions pane, then check the "Enable remote connections" box and any other settings you want to change here, then click 'Apply' and 'Start' on the Actions pane again.

That should hopefully let you connect, with proper credentials, to the service from a remote machine. (If the correct ports and stuff are opened and all that jazz.)

I think this helps your situation.  At least you won't get 403's but you may have some other MsDeploy error.

Comment: I had the same problem. I believe my config was corrupt due to a hard reboot during a config change. I took these steps, but didn't change anything. (Changed auth to Windows only, Apply, and then back to Windows + ISS Mgr). That fixed it for me.

Comment: @KaseySpeakman Thanks. Something about the way the service is installed and/or IIS manager for some reason requires this. Maybe the configuration doesn't get reset unless changes are detected. Finally got this working after flipping auth back and forth and restarting the service like you suggested. (Just restarting the service alone didn't work.)

Comment: The next error will be **Not Found** . To fix it go *Add and remove programs* find your *Web Deploy* click *Change* then install all features.

Comment: I had the same error on Window Server 2012 R2 and Web Deploy 3.6. The problem was webdeploy wasn't completely installed at first it asked to restart the machine. So when I restarted the server and launched [WPI](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) again the installation continued and everything worked. But after restart the WPI won't start so I had to launch it manually. Hope this will help some seeking similar problems.

Comment: Other resolutions include uninstalling Web Deploy 3.6 and installing 3.5. Worked for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32004797/error-the-configuration-section-system-webserver-management-delegation-canno

Comment: What made me laugh is that after spending an hour or so following all of the MS doc Web Deploy installation articles and Troubleshooting Web Deploy articles word-for-word, none of them mentioned that simple checkbox _"Enable Remote Connections"_ and you **STILL** have to do that _Add and remove programs_ fix. smh. Fail.

Comment: @CihanYakar You earned a cookie from me. Thank you.

Comment: I had the same problem but I already had the checkbox "Enable remote connections" checked. So, I solved just restarting "Management Service".

Comment: In my IIS there isn't "Connections" list but "Management Service"

Comment: Please take a look at Lee Gunn's answer below, saved me a lot of time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48283631/10307728

Comment: What a pain in the a** of a program. Should have stayed with the file copy deployment option, but once you've started the process you don't really want to give up.

Comment: @CihanYakar Are you a wizard?!

Answer (score 9):

Web Deploy can give you a whole bunch of errors if not setup correctly. **Do yourself a favour** and use the **Web Platform Installer** (https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx). You should uninstall WebDeploy first if you've already tried to install it. From the WebPI select: "Web Deploy 3.6 for Hosting Servers".

Comment: Had the same problems 6 months later. Just read my own answer and installed "Web Deploy 3.6 for Hosting Servers". Everything works first time :)

Comment: This worked for me, I had installed "Web Deploy 3.6" From **Web Platform Installer**, the key was uninstalling that and installing "Web Deploy 3.6 for Hosting Servers" instead. Worked right away, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Talk about jumping through hoops...
The solution requires set up of user and deployment permissions etc.

1. after getting the error 'NOT FOUND' as predicted by Cihan Yakar
   above, I had to change webdeploy (for me it required re-download search for 'WebDeploy_x64_en-US.msi')
   enabling all options.
2. got a new error, always good, ERROR_USER_NOT_AUTHORIZED_FOR_CONTENTPATH. for this I looked at the web deploy errors (see below for link).

> Diagnosis - A non-administrative user attempted to perform an
>   operation with a Web Deploy provider for which the user is not
>   currently authorized. Resolution - Web Deploy 2.0 setup, by default,
>   creates Management Service Delegation Rules which allow
>   non-administrators to perform operations with this provider. It is
>   possible that a delegation rule required for this provider has not
>   been setup correctly. Workaround: From the Programs Control Panel, run
>   Repair on Web Deploy 2.0. Alternatively, create the delegation rule
>   manually.

It turns out I had to create it manually from 'Configure the Web Deployment Handler'(see below for link), using this guide to 'Configure WMSVC and IIS Manager Permissions' and 'Create Delegation Rules for Web Deploy Users' sorted the problem.

notes:
Diagnosed using 'web deploy error codes' from:
http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes
and eventually configured using processes from 'Configure the Web Deployment Handler':
http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler

Comment: All the sequence of problems solved in one post, this helped. Also there is another work  around, i have uninstalled web deploy and re installed along with IIS: recommended configuration from Web Platform Installer.

Comment: I'm stuck on your #2 ..and i can't for the life of me figure it out. you don't happen to remember any "gotcha's" do you? i've been working on resolving this error for about 6 hours now... and i used your two links extensively during it. i just don't know what else i may be missing.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after Enable remote connections checkbox, I need to reinstall Web Deploy to make it work.