# How to enable remote connections in IIS Management Service?

Tags: iis-7.5

After following [MsDeploy is returning 403 forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325259/msdeploy-is-returning-403-forbidden)
so that I could deploy a Web Api project, I ran across this issue:

The "Enable remote connections" checkbox is disabled in the IIS Management Service for the server node.
The Web Management Service is in the Started state.
I have recycled the management service.
I have recycled the server.
I have local admin.

All controls on this page are disabled.
How do I enable the controls so that I may enable remote connections?

Answer (score 1):

Easy, you just have to stop the service first. It's in the right hand action panel on that page.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Manager, select your server in the connections pane on the left, then go to Management Service at the bottom of the right hand pane.

The options will be greyed out, so stop the service using the options on the far right. Tick 'Enable Remote Connections' at the top.

If with the service restarted deploying results in a 404 Not Found error, go to Add/Remove Programs on the server, right click Microsoft Web Deploy > Change, and add all missing features from the installation options.