# Error when trying to publish asp.net mvc application to aws using web deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

when I try to publish an asp.net mvc application to aws using web deploy an error occurs saying **could not connect to remote computer. the remote server returned an error: (403) forbidden**

please help

[an image of the error is attached below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Es6s.png)

Comment: I don't know AWS very well but I think you have to set firewall rules to make your server accessible on different ports. Check the ports you need for web deploy and make sure they're open and that requests from the IP that you're deploying from is allowed through.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the response. I got it to work. The issue was in the settings of web deploy in IIS. You need to allow remote connections in the setting of web deploy in IIS to allow remote computers to publish web applications to the server.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325259/msdeploy-is-returning-403-forbidden